# What connector is this?

Tags: connector, hardware

I need a cable for something I'm working on, but I don't want to just cut off the connector for the existing cable, can you help be identify the type of connector this is so I can buy a new connector make a new cable and I don't have to ruin this cable?

Oh, and if it helps, this is a connector from inside a tablet for a wacom digitizer.

edit: oops, forgot to include measurements, it's somewhere between 1/2 an inch and 9/16 of an inch wide. and 1/16th of an inch thick

[image: The metal part looks blue because of a reflection]

Comment: It is really hard to guess its size from that photo

Comment: Sorry, I thought I put that in the original post, it's a bit bigger than half an inch, about twice as wide as a normal #2 pencil

Comment: You can still edit the post. What about exact values? My car is also bigger than half an inch, and the last time I used a pencil was probably in the 90s...

Comment: I just broke out the actual ruler and updated the post.

Comment: An unshrouded connector with the same pin spacing might work.... if not an exact match.

Comment: I struggled to identify, but a gut feeling is saying LVDS.